# Diary appoinment variables is void:

Tags: diary

Reference to [31.10.6 Diary Appointments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Appointments.html#Appointments)

> If you have a diary entry for an appointment, and that diary entry
>   begins with a recognizable time of day, Emacs can warn you in advance
>   that an appointment is pending. Emacs alerts you to the appointment by
>   displaying a message in your chosen format, as specified by the
>   variable *appt-display-format*. If the value of *appt-audible* is non-nil,
>   the warning includes an audible reminder. In addition, if
>   *appt-display-mode-line* is non-nil, Emacs displays the number of
>   minutes to the appointment on the mode line.

it mentioned the variables of `appt-display-format`, `appt-audible` and `appt-display-mode-line`,
Unfortunately, I cannot find the variables with prefix of `appt`

eval `(appt-audible)` but  report :
 Symbol’s function definition is void: appt-audible

Why I cannot not find the variables of appointments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library `appt.el` contains the variables/functions sought.  Consider using something like `(require 'appt)` before attempting to locate (with functions such as `describe-...` or `find-...`) and/or before attempting to use the variables/functions.

**Q**:  How did I find the answer to this question?

**A**:  I grepped the `lisp` folder (of the Emacs source code) for the prefix `appt-`, and/or, grepped for a random variable described in the Emacs manual (to which a link was provided in the question by the O.P. above); e.g., `appt-display-format`.